# apply conditional if loop over groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a grouped dataframe in pandas, and I'd like to assign the enviro column a value based on the values for each member in group. In this case, I'm trying to assign the enviro column the value 1 if any member of the group has a 1 in grouped['a'], 'sunny' in grouped['b'], and 14 in grouped['temp']. In the case that every member of the group has a pressure column = 11, every enviro in the group should be 3. I tried the following code, but it threw an error.

```
for num in range(1,501):
    if any(grouped.get_group(num)['a'] == 1) & any(grouped.get_group(num)['b'] == 'sunny') & any(grouped.get_group(num)['cm'] == 1):
       grouped.groups['enviro'] == 1
    if all(grouped.get_group(num)['pressure'] == 11):
       grouped.groups['enviro'] == 3
```

How might I do this?

Edit: corrected the typos in the code I provided.
Edit: corrected again

Comment: What error did it throw?

Comment: Besides `&` should be replaced with `and`. Your description is confusing and the code probably doesn't do what you want. Are you trying to loop through all groups? `grouped.groups['temp'] == 14` probably won't work, right? Please try to clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: The error was: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:9: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Answer (score 1):

`&` is a bitwise `and`.

Replace `&` with `and` for a logical `and`.